# Can we prove that some non-cardinal ordinals are regular?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Usually the notion of cofinality is used for cardinals, though there seems to be no problem defining it for non-cardinal limit ordinals also: the *cofinality* of a limit $\alpha$ is the least $\gamma$ such that there is a less than $\gamma$ sequence of ordinals less than $\gamma$ such that the $\operatorname{sup}$ of the sequence is $\alpha$. But running through some examples leaves me wondering whether the notion is interesting: $\operatorname{cf} (\omega \cdot n) = \omega$, and $\operatorname{cf}(\epsilon_0) = \omega$, since $\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, \dots$ is a confinal sequence.

My question is, can we prove that some non-cardinal ordinals are regular? More particularly, are there any countable ordinals that can be proven regular?

Comment: In fact, many texts define [cofinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) for ordinals. You can find some of then using [google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=v8fNwmk7g4kC&pg=PA49&dq=cofinality+ordinal&q=cofinality+ordinal&redir_esc=y#v=onepage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Every regular ordinal is a cardinal.

The reason is simple, if $\alpha$ is not a cardinal, then it has a bijection with some smaller $\gamma$. This bijection is a sequence of order type $\gamma$ which is cofinal in $\alpha$. Therefore the cofinality of $\alpha$ is at most $\gamma<\alpha$.

If you want this sequence to be strictly increasing you can inductively thin out the sequence resulting from the bijection, at each step either you have finished and have an order type smaller than $\gamma$ or you will have a strictly increasing sequence of order type $\gamma$. Either way, we have $<\alpha$.

Comment: thanks for the answer Asaf!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say "This bijection is a sequence $\gamma \to \alpha$ whose image is a cofinal subset of $\alpha$"?

Comment: Well, what *is* a sequence? It's a function from some set. And since the image of the bijection is $\alpha$ itself, of course it's cofinal.

Comment: I think that there is a substitution of concepts here. We're looking for a sequence (or a function) whose **image** has order type $\gamma$, but the bijection you're using is a function whose **domain** has order type $\gamma$, which is not the same. Thus in terms of the definition of the cofinality of ordinals, the conclusion "Therefore the cofinality of $\alpha$ is at most $\gamma$" in the second paragraph is premature.

Comment: @John: Have you read the **entire** answer?

Comment: Yes, I've read it and I don't say that it is incomplete. I say that it is unprecise and somewhat confusing.

Comment: @John: If only "the smallest cardinality of an unbounded set" could also work as a definition of cofinality... Ah, that alternative future sounds awesome.

Comment: But cofinality of ordinal is an ordinal and not a cardinal by definition, and I think that this definition (which sounds "stronger" than the definition for cardinals) is reasoned because the order is the very thing that distinguishes them. We not only need to find a cofinal subset of the lowest cardinality but of the lowest **order**.

Comment: 'Inductively thin out the sequence resulting from the bijection'. Does this detailed version work?
Denote 'the sequence resulting from the bijection' by $\{a_i:i \in \gamma \}$. Define a function f on $\gamma$ by this process: 
1. f(0) = max {1, $a_0$}.
2.for $\alpha < \gamma$, let I($\alpha$)={$i \in \gamma:i \ge \alpha \ and \  \forall \beta < \alpha, \ a_i > a_{\beta}$}, if I($\alpha$)=$\emptyset$, let f($\alpha$)=0, else let j = inf I($\alpha$), f($\alpha$)= $a_j$.
Let I = {$i \in \gamma: f(i) = 0$}, k = inf I, then $f|_k$ is the required strictly increasing k-sequence.

Comment: @Michael: Admittedly, this is very hard for me to understand (both because of the fact the mathy parts are mixed MathJax and text, and the fact that comments are hard to fully understand in this context). But the idea is quite simple, let $f\colon\gamma\to\alpha$ be a bijection, then define recursively $g$, by stating that if $g$ was defined for all ordinals below $\xi$, then $g(\xi)=f(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is the least greater ordinal $\geq\xi$ such that $f(\zeta)$ is an upper bound to $g``\xi$ (which was defined). If no such $\zeta$ exists, $g$ is already cofinal.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main idea of my formulation. Thanks for your clarification!