# Recursive way of calculating cofinality of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

I was trying to understand why

> A regular ordinal is always an initial ordinal.

and in the course of this, came to the following hypothesis.

For any ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$\omega_{\alpha} \le \beta < \omega_{\alpha + 1}$$
where $\omega_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-th infinite initial ordinal and $\beta\,$ is a limit ordinal, we have
$$\mathrm {cf} (\beta) = \mathrm {cf} (\omega_{\alpha}) =
\begin{cases}
\mathrm {cf} (\alpha), & \text{if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal} \\
\omega_{\alpha},  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then we could simply use transfinite induction to prove the above fact since $\alpha < \omega_{\alpha} \le \beta$. Is the hypothesis true? If it isn't, how to prove the initial statement?

Comment: No, your hypothesis is not true. For example, $\text{cf}(\omega_1+\omega) = \omega$, while $\text{cf}(\omega_1) = \omega_1$.

Comment: On the other hand, your evaluation of $\text{cf}(\omega_\alpha)$ as $\text{cf}(\alpha)$ or $\omega_\alpha$ is correct. But note that it might not always be helpful, since there are (limit) ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\omega_\alpha = \alpha$, in which case you get $\text{cf}(\omega_\alpha) = \text{cf}(\alpha) = \text{cf}(\omega_\alpha)$.

Comment: Note that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146601/can-we-prove-that-some-non-cardinal-ordinals-are-regular already sort of answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see this is not the case. Since there are $\omega_{\alpha+1}$ many such $\beta$, it follows that for any $\mu<\alpha$, we can get $\mu$ many ordinals and take their supremum to construct an ordinal with cofinality less than $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_\alpha)$.

For example, we have

$$\omega_1\le\omega_1+\omega<\omega_2$$

but

$$\operatorname{cof}(\omega_1+\omega)=\omega$$

The gist of why regular ordinals are initial ordinals is that if it bijected a smaller ordinal, you could construct a cofinal sequence with length smaller than itself. More details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146608).